# Codificador personalizado

Tags: c#, criptografía

Estoy iniciando con C# y tengo unas cuantas dudas sobre un ejercicio de hacer un decodificador.

Tengo por ejemplo un string con todos los caracteres normales.

Ejemplo:

```
string normalCaracters = abcdefg;
```

y tengo el string codificador:

```
string codifiedString = X3Dsx;
```

Donde a = X, b = 3, c = D etc.

La idea es que en un TextBox se introduzca un string y que al presionar el botón en el otro TextBox aparezca el equivalente pero ya codificado según el string de codificación.

He intentado utilizar el método Replace() de esta manera:

```
string textEntry = 'Manzana';
string textOut = textEntry.replace('M', '3').replace('a','W')... etc
```

Pero esto aparte de que no es nada fácil y manual, no devuelve el valor esperado.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar el **tipo de datos Dictionary**. Un diccionario no es más que una estructura de tipo **llave-valor**, en tu caso la llave puede ser el caracter original y el valor podría ser el valor por el que será reemplazado el caracter original.

A continuación el código:

```
Dictionary<char, char> Cifrado = new Dictionary<char, char>();
string textoOriginal = "abc";
string textoCifrado = "";

Cifrado['a'] = 'X';
Cifrado['b'] = '3';
Cifrado['c'] = 'D';
//Se continúan llenado los caracteres originales y su caracter sustituto.

foreach (var x in textoOriginal)
{
   textoCifrado += Cifrado[x]; 
}

txtBox1.Text = textoCifrado;
```

Aquí se declara un diccionario tal como se explicó antes y se llena con los correspondientes caracteres(los originales y los que se usarán para cifrar los originales). Se hace un **ciclo foreach** que recorrerá la cadena a cifrar, y utilizando el diccionario cada caracter se sustituirá por el caracter que se utiliza para cifrar. Una vez que se sale del **ciclo foreach** pues se muestra en el **TextBox** la cadena ya cifrada.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. Me funciono correctamente.